# pip install mysqlclient on cloudlinux

Tags: mysql, pip, cloudlinux

I can't install mysqlclient on my cpanel cloudlinux server. It show this issue when i activate the project source and trying to install mysqlclient.

```
Collecting mysqlclient

Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      mysql_config --version
      ['10.3.34']
      mysql_config --libs
      ['-L/usr/lib64/', '-lmariadb']
      mysql_config --cflags
      ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
      ext_options:
        library_dirs: ['/usr/lib64/']
        libraries: ['mariadb']
        extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
        extra_link_args: []
        include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,0,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.1.0')]
      /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,1,0,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.0 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for mysqlclient did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      mysql_config --version
      ['10.3.34']
      mysql_config --libs
      ['-L/usr/lib64/', '-lmariadb']
      mysql_config --cflags
      ['-I/usr/include/mysql', '-I/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
      ext_options:
        library_dirs: ['/usr/lib64/']
        libraries: ['mariadb']
        extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
        extra_link_args: []
        include_dirs: ['/usr/include/mysql', '/usr/include/mysql/mysql']
        extra_objects: []
        define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,0,'final',0)"), ('__version__', '2.1.0')]
      /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
      .....
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fno-semantic-interposition -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,1,0,'final',0) -D__version__=2.1.0 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
      unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
      error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> mysqlclient

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I faced with Macbook M1-Pro chip.
Now I am able to connect mysql using *mysqlclient*.

**Run**

```
xcode-select --install
brew install zstd
pip install pymysql
pip install wheel 
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix)/lib" pip install mysqlclient==<version>
```

**Then**
Put

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

in your settings file at top if you are using django or any other framework

*If you don’t want commit this change in your code and using django then*
Put

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

before

```
import MySQLdb as Database
```

in env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py

install all other dependency if required.
*example*

1. pip install mysql-connector-python
2. pip install cryptography